# overflow:hidden and float:left on IE6

Tags: css, css-float

Just to frame you. Look at the following code.

Basically I have a table inside a div. When the table gets too big the overflow hidden triggers.

PROBLEM: in IE6 the "some text" gets hidden as expected but the floated span not.
Is there a way around of fix it?

```
#wrap{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:20px
}
span{
    float:left;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}

<div id="wrap">
  <table>
     <tr>
        <td><span></span> some text</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><span></span> some text</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><span></span> some text</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I know you probably *have* to support IE6, because its in your spec.... but if not - if there's any possibility you can drop support for it, please please please do so. IE6 really *really* needs to die.

Comment: I understand. I would give 1 month paycheck just to get rid of IE6.

Comment: But in the other hand ~5% of my visitors use IE6.

Comment: I don't see the problem, this looks correct in IE6. Just tested it and it's the same as Firefox.

Comment: I officially discontinue IE6 from all my projects. I feel a new person already...

Answer (score 1):

Try giving height:1%; for ie6 css. as below.

## wrap{

```
overflow:hidden;
height:%;
```

}